# Getting getDeclaredMethods() to match a varargs method

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

I want to use `getDeclaredMethod()` to find a method with this signature:

```
public void foo(String inArg1, Object... inArgs);
```

Using this call:

```
Class<?>[] argClasses = { String.class, Integer.class };
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo", argClasses);
```

But it generates a `NoSuchMethodException` exception. However, it is possible to invoke the method (assuming you find it some other way):

```
Object[] args = { "arg1", new Integer(2) };
m.invoke(instance, args);
```

I could list them all, with `getDeclaredMethods()`, and then try to do the signature matching myself, but that seems like a lot of work.

Should what I want to do be possible? Am I just missing something dumb?

Comment: you probably need to pass Object[].class instead of Integer.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is *callable* with any object(s) because it is *declared* to accept object(s). - But, because it is *declared* with `Object` type you won't find via `getDeclaredMethod()` if you don't search for the exact *declared* type.

You should be able, though, to iterate over all declared methods and check on their [parameter types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29) to see if they are [assignable from](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) your given type to find all methods which are *callable* with your parameters.

Example:

```
Class[] signature = {String.class, Integer.class};
Method[] methods = someClass.getDeclaredMethods();

for ( Method m : methods ) {
  Class[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
  if ( params.length == signature.length ) {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < signature.length && params[i].isAssignableFrom( signature[i] ); i++ ) {

    }
    if ( i == signature.length ) {
      System.out.println("Found matching method: " + m.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have not checked which type(s) `Object...` actually *is* assignable from. I assume that it is not `Integer` but rather `Integer[]` since the varargs are compiled to arrays.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but yes, this is the conclusion I came to as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A vararg argument is just syntactic sugar for an array. The signature of the method is

```
foo(String, Object[]);
```

and not

```
foo(String, Integer);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But it's perfectly legal to call foo("arg1", 2), and so it seems it should match as I suggest above (I my assertion of the invocation may be wrong, though).

Here's the thing. I'm trying to map a call in a DSL I'm implementing to a "native" Java method. I get the arguments as an array, and I need to match any method that might fit the bill. If getDeclaredMethod() would match it, this would be easy.

Comment: A method only has one signature. It's legal because the compiler searches for a method whose signature is compatible with the arguments. But that doesn't change the signature of the method.

Answer (score 3):

You should treat `varargs` as an array:

```
Class<?>[] argClasses = { String.class, Object[].class };
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo", argClasses);
```

Comment: Seems to be the actual answer

Answer (score 3):

The only legal way to find foo method is

```
Class<?>[] argClasses = { String.class, Object[].class };
Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("foo", argClasses);
```

as for

```
Object[] args = { "arg1", new Integer(2) };
m.invoke(instance, args);
```

it's quite legal, just as calling foo without reflection

```
foo("str", new Integer(2));
```